# Why is my question taking me to "page not found"

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked one question here a few hours ago. Now that question is taking me to `page not found`.
This is my question, 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85123/how-can-i-earn-money-by-chrome-extensions.

Where has it gone?

Comment: Your question was off topic for **Meta** Stack Overflow and was closed and then deleted.

Comment: ok i understand , where can i ask this question in stack my question was exactly this one http://malaysia.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110318175736AAm4woT

Comment: The question has already been asked on Programmers.StackExchange - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/55768/charging-for-chrome-extension

Comment: For the record, when there is duplicate question in the same site the question is closed and link to the duplicate question appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that your question is **deleted**.

If you have not deleted the question yourself, then it must be some moderator and reason could be your question had no upvotes and no answers too and the question was not useful on the SO site.

However you do have a point, that there is no information of any sort saying why your question was deleted, if it was done by moderator.

Comment: ok where can i ask that kind of qustion?

Comment: @gowri - I do not know what your question was and hence cannot comment on that. However, I feel a moderator can give answer to your question.

Answer (score 4):

Your question was deleted by a moderator because it was way off-topic for Meta Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) before posting.